# Spring MVC(Spring 2.5) Question about Post-Redirect-Get

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Annonted Controller that is used to capture the information from a form and get a list of search results from the database.

Here is the definition of the method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {SUBMIT_BTN }) 
public ModelAndView processForm(@ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME){


   // 1. Load search results using search parameters from form (Contained in a collection of some sort)


   // 2. Create the ModelAndView 

   // 3. Redirect with RequestView or redirect: to generate a GET. 
}
```

I think I need to redirect with redirect: since i have a list of items in a collection store in the session.  Cannot add that as a url request param.

Basically I'm trying to prevent problems whith the back button where it says that the page is expired.  I want to implement the PRG pattern in strings.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around converting the POST into a GET.  Can I just redirect or do I need two methods? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 6):

The standard pattern is to have a controller method to handle the GET,and which shows the form (or whatever) to the user, and one to handle the POST, which is the form submission.  The POST method sends a redirect after it has finished processing the submission, which comes back in to the GET method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myapp", method=GET) 
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME){
   return "form.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/myapp", method=POST) 
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME){
   // do stuff to process for submission
   return "redirect:/myapp";
}
```

Returning a view name with the "redirect:" prefix forces Spring to send an HTTP direct rather than an internal request forward.

This is the same pattern that Spring 2.0 implemented with `SimpleFormController`, but the new way is far more transparent.